# Sencha Touch 2 - setActiveItem of card layout inside navigationview issue

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have an Ext.Panel with a card layout nested inside a navigation view. I did this to easily switch between a map and a list without having to pop and then push a whole different view (basically to avoid the animation). So, I have a button in the navigationBar that fires an action in the controller. This initial view, with a list, load fine, but the controller code to switch between the views (using setActiveItem()) does not work. No error message. I found something about a bug where you have to call show(). Although this works, it overlays the new activeItem (the Map, in this case) on top of the navigaionBar! (see screenshot). Also, if I just change activeItem to 1 in the config of the wrapper manually, it shows the map just fine, same as the list.

My wrapper panel looks like this:

```
Ext.define(ViewInfos.VendorWrapper.ViewName,{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    id:     ViewInfos.VendorWrapper.PanelId,
    xtype:  ViewInfos.VendorWrapper.Xtype,

    config:
    {
        layout: 'card',
        title:      Resources.VendorsNearby,
        activeItem: 0,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: ViewInfos.VendorList.Xtype, //Initially shown, a list
            },
            {
                xtype: ViewInfos.VendorMap.Xtype, //What I'm trying to show, a map
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

and here is my controller code:

```
Ext.define('OrderMapper.controller.VendorWrapper', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
           vendorMap:           ViewInfos.VendorMap.Xtype,
           vendorList:          ViewInfos.VendorList.Xtype,
           vendorWrapper:       ViewInfos.VendorWrapper.Xtype,
           main:                ViewInfos.Main.Xtype,
           vendorToggleButton: (ViewInfos.Main.Xtype + ' button[action=vendorViewToggle]')
        },
        control: {
            vendorToggleButton:{
                tap: function(){
                    var curView = this.getVendorWrapper().getActiveItem().id;

                    //active view == VendorList
                    if(curView == 'VendorList'){

                        //this shows up in the console
                        console.log('vendorToggleButton tapped, switching to map');

                        this.getVendorWrapper().setActiveItem(1);

                        //without this line, the view doesn't even change
                        this.getVendorWrapper().show();
                        this.getVendorToggleButton().setText('List');
                    }

                    //active view == VendorMap
                    else if (curView == 'VendorMap'){
                        console.log('vendorToggleButton tapped, switching to list');
                        this.getVendorWrapper().setActiveItem(0);
                        this.getVendorToggleButton().setText('Map');

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the screenshot of the wonky view that happens on `this.getVendorWrapper().show()`
[image: Screenshot]

Also, I tried changing the wrapper to a Carousel (instead of a regular panel with a card layout), and the carousel will swipe to change list/map but setActiveItem() STILL doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, your question is answered you need to accept the right answer by click on the check symbol next to the answer. it's a way of thanking the guy who found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently working on a **navigation.View** where there is basically 4 main views from where you can push other subview. I did it like this :

```
Ext.define('App.view.Navigation', {
  requires: [
    ...
  ],

  xtype: 'mainviews',

  extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

  config: {
    cls: 'content',
    layout:{animation:false}, // or whatever animation you want for push and pop
    navigationBar: {
      ...
    },
    items: [{
      xtype: 'container',
      layout:'card',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'mainview1',
      },{
        xtype: 'mainview2',
      },{
        xtype: 'mainview3',
      },{
        xtype: 'mainview4',
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

Then it's really easy to either set the active item of the navigation view or push subviews

For instance, in a controller it would be

```
this.getMainviews().setActiveItem(X); // X = 0,1,2 or 3
```

and

```
this.getMainviews.push(view); // view = the view your want to push
```

and these is the references :

```
refs:{
  mainviews: 'mainviews'
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you just want to avoid the animation on `push`/`pop`, add this `config` to your navigation view:

```
layout: {
    animation: null
}
```

Generally, you should not call `.show()` on items that are inside your `Ext.navigation.View` instance. They will be added to `Ext.Viewport` directly, thus appearing to be on top of the navigation bar.

**Have a look at [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aatiis/ukMRf/)**, might give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Now I understand `show()`, but, I do want the animation every other time I `push`. And I want map and list to `pop` to the same previous view. Should I just turn animation off, `pop` the list, `push` the map, the turn animation back on with `setLayout({...})`? That seems like overkill.